# Injecting html from MVC site by jquery (XSS?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, xss

I created an MVC 5 site with a controller/partial view that generate some html data (a list of items). I also wrote a .js file that contains a jquery to fetch the data from the MVC site. This javascript file is used on other sites to retrieve the data and insert it in their own sites.

This works perfectly well when I use the js file on my localhost connecting to a remote server, or when both client (page with js file) and server (MVC-site) or on the same server. That makes me think this is some kind of XSS-issue. My question: how can I solve this or what is the best approach.

My code (.js)

```
function lookup(elementId)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: host + elementId + '?rnd=' + Math.random(),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (html) {
            var elements = $("div[data-id='" + elementId + "']");

            if (elements.length > 0) {
                elements[0].innerHTML = html;
            }
        },                
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var elements = $("div[data-id='" + elementId + "']");
            alert(xhr.status);
            if (elements.length > 0) {
                elements[0].innerHTML = "An error occurred.";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The call enters the error function, but de xhr.status is 0.

Any suggestions or optimizations to the code?

**UPDATE**: My site (containing the MVC) is hosted on azurewebsites.net

Comment: are you sure your script is being loaded okay in your ASP.NET site, and is jQuery included as well?

Comment: Well, the error block is entered, so the block 

elements[0].innerHTML = "An error occurred.";

is executed successfully.

Isn't that proof that the jQuery is loaded okay?